# Adobe AIR ContextMenu - right clicking and roll out

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am in the process of converting a web-based actionscript project to AIR.  There appears to be some subtle differences in the way that context menus are handled between the web and air versions of actionscript, and the (rather large) codebase that I'm converting relies on one of those subtleties for handling context menus.

For the purposes of this question, let's take a very simple AIR application:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.NativeMenu;
    import flash.display.NativeMenuItem;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class test extends Sprite
    {
        private var menu:NativeMenu;
        private var menuItem:NativeMenuItem;
        public function test()
        {
            menu = new NativeMenu();
            menuItem = new NativeMenuItem("Menu Item");
            menu.addItem(menuItem);

            var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
            s.graphics.clear();
            s.graphics.beginFill(0x65ffff, 1);
            s.graphics.drawRect(0,0, 100, 100);
            s.graphics.endFill();
            s.x = 10;
            s.y = 10;
            this.addChild(s);

            s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, rightClick);
            s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, rollOut);
            s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollOver);

        }

        private function rightClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("right click");
            menu.display(stage, event.stageX, event.stageY);
        }

        private function rollOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("roll out");
        }

        private function rollOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("roll over");
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I run this app and right-click four times on the blue sprite.  I would expect to receive roll over and roll out events each time before and after the context menu is displayed.  Instead I receive this output in the debugger log:

```
roll over
right click
roll out
right click
right click
roll over
roll out
right click
```

The first click works as expected.  But the next two clicks do not generate either a roll over or a roll out.  And even more strangely, the forth click generates a roll over, then a roll out and afterwards a right click.

The reason that this is a problem is because the legacy code I'm converting, which again was written for web-based actionscript, depends on this roll over and roll out behavior to change the context menu items that will be displayed.  It works in the web-based version because these events are triggered in the same order every time the user right-clicks: roll over, right click, roll out.  But as we see here, this is not the case with AIR.

I realize that one approach to fixing this would be to change the way the app works, so that it assigns different context menus to different sprites as needed, but I'm looking for a way to maintain the same approach as the legacy system to minimize the number of changes I need to make.

So my question is: Is there a way to have AIR consistently generate roll over and roll out events in the same order, before and after displaying the menu, every time the user right-clicks on the sprite?

Comment: To be clear, when you're right clicking, you want the roll events to dispatch even if the mouse hasn't left the bounds of the object between clicks?

Comment: @Batman: Yes, all of the right clicks occur within the bounds of the same object

Comment: The mouse has to move for those events to dispatch. When the menu comes up, it takes the focus (which will dispatch the rollout on the square).  When you close the menu, the focus should return to the app, but you won't get a roll over event until the mouse moves. (so if you right click without moving the mouse, it will exhibit the behavior you've shown)

Comment: @Batman: I'm not sure if you mean something else, but the tests that I did definitely involved mouse movement, but all of that mouse movement occurred within the bounds of the same object/sprite.  It appears that after a context menu is displayed, right clicking usually doesn't return focus to the clicked object

Comment: I tried your example, worked for me in AIR 15 - assuming I move the mouse after the menu closes prior to right-clicking again.

Comment: @Batman: Thanks for trying it out!  Ok, I see what you're saying now.  Yes the same works for me as well (I have AIR 18).  But what I want to be able to do is: 1. Right click to display the menu.  2. Move the mouse outside the bounds of the menu, but still inside the same sprite. 3. Right click to hide the current menu and display the same menu again.  This seems to work fine in the web version but not in AIR.